# how to use signals and slots in blackberry cascades

Tags: blackberry-10

1. how to read data from QML page using signals
2. how to wite received data in another QML page using signals

i excatly expect qtsignals and slots concepts. please anybody tell how to read and wrote data from qml page.

Comment: Have a look at the guide on how to ask a good question so you can edit in some details to let us help you. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following syntax and get sample from github

**1.HPP FILE**

```
Q_PROPERTY(QString companyname READ companyname WRITE setcompanyname NOTIFY companynameChanged)
void companynameChanged();
void setcompanyname(const QString &company);
       QString companyname() const;
QString m_company;
```

---

**2.CPP FILE**

```
void ApplicationUI::setcompanyname(const QString &company)
{
    if (m_company == company)
        return;

    m_company = company;
    emit companynameChanged();
}

QString ApplicationUI::companyname() const
{
    return m_company;
}
```

---

------------------- Get sample full code from here ([CLICK HERE](https://github.com/svmrajesh/BB-10-Cascades/tree/master/MY%20APPS/signalsANDslots))-----------